# Do solar flares increase the probability of an earthquake?

Tags: geology, causality

So, with Japan in the news today, weird theories about earthquakes are at the forefront again.   The theory that solar flares are correlated with earthquakes came up, so of course I tried to find some information online.  To my surprise there seems to be quite a bit.  Does [this](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2007AGUSMIN33A..03J) appear to be credible research?

Comment: i don't think so.they just increase the probability of electronics failing., and overexposure to radiation.

Comment: Related question that might be of your interest: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/13131/11908

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NASA data would indicate that there is no *causal* relationship.  [With the sheer number of earthquakes that are happening on the earth on a daily basis](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eqarchives/year/eqstats.php), there is absolutely a correlation in *time* between any solar flare and the earthquake itself (just like the [clustering illusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_illusion)), thus people will tend to commit the [post hoc ergo propter hoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc) fallacy.  However, the causal relation ship is not established, and would seem to be tenuous at best.  Considering the very disparate causes and mechanisms related to each phenomenon, the link is very unlikely.

Some additional information:  Along with solar flares, there is speculation about the "super moon" causing the earthquake in Japan.  [This is also easily debunked](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/badastronomy/2011/03/11/no-the-supermoon-didnt-cause-the-japanese-earthquake/).

EDIT:  A geologist associate of mine also [has this to say about the earthquake in Japan](http://georneys.blogspot.com/2011/03/why-are-there-earthquakes-and-volcanoes.html#more).  Some good info in layman terms I think.

Comment: There is no causal relationship and there can never be. Solar flares have no interaction with the drivers behind [plate tectonics](http://pubs.usgs.gov/gip/dynamic/unanswered.html).

Comment: Look also https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/13131/11908